# Error in calling the crystal report using Show() method in button click

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm new in c# and trying to pass textbox value in crystal report
I'm using VB 2010 and Crystal 13 version. 
I used this code to call the report:

```
Prescription myPresc = new Prescription();
myPresc.Show();
```

Under the 'Show' appears a red line saying:

> 'CHIS.Prescription' does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no
>   extension method 'Show' accepting a first argument of type
>   'CHIS.Prescription'  could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Help me please don't really know what to do.

Comment: And what `Prescription` is? Is it your viewer?

Comment: What is base class of `Prescription`? The compiler basically is saying that class `Prescription` does not have method `Show`

Comment: Thanks guys for your response I just realize I can't call the crystal report by itself. So now I created a windows form and put the crystal report in there.